# Advantages of Lebesgue measurable sets over Borel ones in $L^p$ theory?

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-integral, lebesgue-measure

Borel $\sigma$-algebra $\mathcal B$ is simply easier to work with (in my opinion) as it behaves well with respect to the topology of our space. Nevertheless, the $\sigma$-algebra $\mathcal M$ of all Lebesgue measurable sets is simply richer. I can conceive that there're probably some interesting stuff going on.

> Suppose $\Omega\subset\Bbb R^n$ be open domain. What are some major differences between $L^p(\Omega,\mathcal B,\mu)$ and $L^p(\Omega,\mathcal M,\mu)$?

Does completeness of $\mathcal M$ allow us to prove some interesting theorems that the structure of $\mathcal B$ is not big enough to support? More generally, what do we gain by replacing $\mathcal B$ with its completion in a more general topological space $X$?

Comment: Not a direct answer, but maybe relevant: Depending on which way you are going, you might simply save work. If you work with outer measures (which incidentally is my favorite way to define the Lebesgue measure), then you get the maximal $\sigma$-algebra (so in this case the Lebesgue-measurable sets) essentially for free. Furthermore, the Caratheodory-criterion gives you an easy way to check for measurability. Of course you might want to check that open/closed sets are measurable at some point, but you do not need to introduce the full Borel $\sigma$-algebra for this.

Comment: @mlk Thank you for your comment, but I must admit that I failed to grasp how it's related to my question. Maybe can you explain a bit more?

Comment: It is not directly related, that is why I only put it as a comment. It is just a possible reason, why one would use one over the other.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In this setting there is no difference at all.

Recall that the elements of $L^p$ are not functions, but equivalence classes of functions, where the equivalence is "equal almost everywhere".  It's a standard measure theory fact that every Lebesgue-measurable function is a.e. equal to some Borel-measurable function (this comes from the fact that $\mathcal{M}$ is the completion of $\mathcal{B}$ with respect to $\mu$).  So the equivalence classes in $L^p(\Omega, \mathcal{M}, \mu)$ are in one-to-one correspondence with those in $L^p(\Omega, \mathcal{B}, \mu)$, and this correspondence is an isometric isomorphism between the Banach spaces.  For all intents and purposes, they are the same space.

The same argument works to compare any measure space with its completion.